# failed to load next.config.js when building using github action

Tags: node.js, bash, amazon-ec2, next.js, github-actions

I am using simple [ssh deploy action](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action) and i have a bash script to build and restart pm2 frontend process.

It's working fine when I run it directly run the script through the ec2 instance but gives error when building through the github action

below is the generated error

It says **Failed to load next.config.js** but its there, I've printed out **pwd** to make sure its the correcy directory. But still the same error

- Node -> 14.17.0
- Next -> 12.0.8
- npm -> 6.14.3

```
out: /home/***/elfswap/elfswap-frontend
out: 
out: > fe-elf@ build /home/***/elfswap/elfswap-frontend
out: > next build
out: 
err: error - Failed to load next.config.js, see more info here https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-config-error
err: 
err: > Build error occurred
err: Error: Not supported
err:     at Object.loadConfig [as default] (/home/***/elfswap/elfswap-frontend/node_modules/next/dist/server/config.js:413:78)
```

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu/project/frontend
git pull origin master
echo "$(pwd)"
npm run build
pm2 restart frontend
```

Comment: Almost the same problem here... Did you find any solutions?

Comment: I couldn't, its not a frequent deployment so kinda stuck manually running the script in server every time

Comment: @DobromirKirov , figured out the problem, answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking back at it with a fresh mind, figured out the problem.

I already knew that remote ssh doesn't load the bash profile, but `node` command was working fine so i didn't look much further.

but after echoing node version in the bash script, found out it was using version 8.*.* from `/usr/local/bin` not the one installed through **nvm**.

So to make it work, I removed `npm`, `node` binaries from `/usr/local/bin` and replaced those with symbolic links from nvm version directory.

Now its working fine.